# Import Database Oracle with SQL Plus

Tags: oracle12c

please help me, actually i'm just import my database with SQL Plus, and its finish, but after it, the database has no row and can't insert a new data

Comment: did you forget the commit?

Comment: can you show the snippet of your sql?

Comment: the extension is dmp file

Comment: why you can't insert a new data? permissions? weren't tables created? you need to be more clear

Comment: i think its a permissions

Comment: you need to show us the error messages. I think it's better you open a new question with an improved text, explaining better.

Answer (score 0):

As you've imported the DMP file, I doubt that you did it with SQL*Plus; DMP files are created by export (data pump) utility and imported with *import* (data pump). No SQL*Plus is involved here.

During the import process, you should have created & reviewed the **LOG** file which says whether import session finished successfully or not. It will also list all errors it encountered, so you should pay attention to that and take steps to eliminate them.

As you don't see anything in tables you imported, something must have gone wrong.

There can be numerous failure reasons; without the LOG file, it is virtually impossible to guess what might be going on in your case. If you can't figure it out, consider posting it (or its meaningful excerpt) here so that someone might assist.